# npm uninstall not working in Mac terminal

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, nvm

I had installed node version 14 using `npm install -g node@14`. Now I tried the below commands to uninstall node version 14, but it's not working.

Commands:

```
$ node -v
v14.19.0

$ npm unisntall node@14
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/*****/package.json
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/*****/package.json
npm WARN ***** No description
npm WARN ***** No repository field
npm WARN ***** No README data
npm WARN ***** No license field

up to date in 0.105s

$ node -v
v14.19.0

$ npm uninstall -g node
up to date in 0.04s

$ node -v
v14.19.0

$ npm uninstall -g node@14.19.0
up to date in 0.049s

$ note -v
v14.19.0
```

Commands in image:

[image: Code Image]

Comment: Please post text rather than images of text.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to install a new version of *Node.js*, then you can simply download it from the website ([nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/)).

When you install a new version and run the installer, it will automatically remove the old version.

---

If you want to remove *Node.js* and *npm* altogether, then you need to follow the steps below.

1. Open the terminal, and navigate to the home directory.
2. Type the following commands (ignore the *$*; they are just to indicate a new command to enter).

   ```
   $ cd /usr
   $ cd local
   $ cd include
   $ ls
   ```
3. Then, delete the *Node* directory by typing in the following command.

   ```
   $ sudo rm -rf node
   ```
4. Go back to the local directory, and enter the `lib` directory by entering the following commands.

   ```
   $ cd ..
   $ cd lib
   ```
5. Delete the `node_modules` folder by entering the following command.

   ```
   $ sudo rm -rf node-modules
   ```
6. To delete *Node* from the `bin` directory, type in the following commands.

   ```
   $ cd ..
   $ cd bin
   $ sudo rm -rf node
   ```
7. *Note:* `npm` and `npx` can both be deleted from the `bin` directory.

Comment: Finally the proper answer. Worked for me, thanks for your contribution.

Comment: No matter what I try I just can't delete node. Tried this method but v16.18.0 is still there.

Comment: @Furkanicus Not sure. Node may have changed things but from my testing, it should still work.

Comment: Finally managed to do it through nvm. It's strange that deleting the file wasn't enough

Answer (score 3):

I've been working with node and macos for many years, and I've moved from node installation to node installation using nvm, which allows me to easily switch and install different versions of node.

You can try removing node this way, in case you installed it with brew

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies node 
brew uninstall --force node
```

##### Bonus - Managing multiple versions of node by installing nvm

```
brew update 
brew install nvm 
mkdir ~/.nvm
```

Then update your bash profile or zsh_profile

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

Add the following content

```
export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh
```

On the command line, update your profile (bash/zsh)

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Installing multiple versions of node

```
nvm install 12
nvm install 14
nvm install 16
```

To use a specific version of node (e.g 16)

```
nvm use 16
```

Comment: This answer mainly only works if _Kumar_ installed _Node.js_ with _Brew_. However, he never said anything about that in the answer. (Maybe add a comment on their question asking if Kumar installed _Node.js_ with _Brew_.)

Comment: nvm install "versionName". e.g. if you want to use node v 16.0.0, then your command should be -> nvm install 16.0.0  also, you can use nvm ls-remote to list all the available versions