# How to uninstall node.js 10.x and npm 6.x.x from macos?

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

I have an old version of node v10.4.1 and npm 6.4.1 running my Mac and want to install the newest NPM 9.

I tried to

```
npm install -g npm@9
```

and to install the .pkg file from the website.

Everytime I check the version via shell

```
$ npm -v
6.4.1
```

Then I tried to uninstall all NPM versions via

```
sudo npm uninstall npm -g
```

and manually like described here [npm uninstall not working in Mac terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71452940/npm-uninstall-not-working-in-mac-terminal)

Nothing works so far. I.e. this is shown

```
$ npm -v
6.4.1
```

How can I make sure everything is cleanly uninstalled?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After 2 hours of fiddling with this I accidently typed in

```
$ npm -b
```

And this dir came up

```
/usr/local/Cellar/node@10
```

After deleting that folder, I found this as well

```
/usr/local/opt/node@10
```

and deleted it as well.

Afterwards I simply used this again

```
$ npm install -g npm@9
```

and ppooff. It shows me after a shell restart

```
$ npm -v
9.3.1
$ node -v
v18.13.0
```

I hope that saves u some time and nerve.